# How to make the following tex work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am trying to draw put some number along `(i,i-1)` where `i` varies from `1` to `10`. I have tried to implement this idea using `foreach` command. But the following code can not be compiled by LaTeX. Do you have any idea to make the following code work or other solutions to do the same function?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \foreach \i/\j in {1/2,2/3,.../...,9/10}{
    \node at (\i cm,\j cm) {(\i,\j)};
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

note that the `foreach` command.

Comment: In your text `j=i-1` but in your code `j=i+1`. I've used `i+1` in my code but, of course, it can be easily modified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's better to let `tikz` calculate the `j` as `i+1`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach[evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] \i in {1,2,...,9}{%
    \node at (\i cm,\j cm) {(\i,\j)};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]